# Getting input from user in different lines with different characters in python

Tags: python, input

How to get **input** like this in *python*?

```
5 3
*..
*..
***
***
***
```

I try for first line by this code:

```
n,m = map(int,input().split())
```

but I don't know how to get 5 line which each of them has 3 element exactly like this.

Comment: The input format isn't clear.

Comment: If you want N inputs, then call `input()` inside a `for x in range(N)` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```py
m, n = map(int, input().split())
elements = [input().split() for _ in range(m)]
'''
When you use the example input,
elements will be [
    ['*', '.', '.'],
    ['*', '.', '.'],
    ['*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*']
]
'''
```